# how to integrate $\frac1{2-3x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we evaluate
$$\int\frac{dx}{2-3x^2}$$

Comment: What is the domain of x?

Comment: It is an indefinite integral, @Priyatham : what do we care about its domain?

Comment: I am sorry, I was thinking of some sine substitution (which is not required here).

Comment: Parentheses, please. It is not clear in the title that the $3x^2$ belongs in the denominator, though it is from context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$2-3x^2=\left(\sqrt2-\sqrt3x\right)\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt3x\right)\implies$$

$$\frac1{2-3x^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2-\sqrt3x}+\frac1{\sqrt2+\sqrt3x}\right)\implies\;\ldots$$

Comment: Nice, thanks...